# How to convert Long Datatype to BLOB datatype in Oracle Dump

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How to convert Long datatype to BLOB datatype in Oracle 10g dump file?

Comment: You can't convert anything in a dump file... it's a proprietary Oracle format that you won't be able to accurately alter. What is your _actual_ problem? Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

You can import the table from the dump file into a database and use the [`TO_LOB` function](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:510622111991) to convert the column to a `CLOB`.  If the column is a `LONG`, it stores character data so you would want to convert it to a `CLOB` not a `BLOB`.  If the column is a `LONG RAW`, it stores binary data so you would want to convert it to a `BLOB`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can convert LONG to BLOB but not directly. Convert LONG to LOB and then convert the LOB to BLOB.